# Cucumber-rails | Defining a step which describe changes in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

What is the best practice to define steps which describe changes in a database?

For example, I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Creating a user
  Given I am on the users creation page
  When I fill in "Name" with "Chandler Bing"
  And I click "Create User"
  Then the user should be added into the database
```

How can I better define the last step:

```
Then /^the user should be added into the database$/ do
  User.count.should eq 1
end
```

Or there's some other, clever way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle) gem which defines many database steps for you and they're really nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this in two ways. First, the web steps have been deprecated in newer versions of Cucumber. Therefor steps like "When I fill in "blah" with "blah"" are now discouraged. Second, testing the number of users in the database isn't describing the full picture. You want to know that the user is the one you created, meaning the same name and whatever other properties you end up adding. To handle these types of steps, I find myself writing scenarios like:

```
Scenario: Creating a user
  When I create the following users:
    | name           |
    | Chandler Bing  |
    | Some Other Guy |
  Then I should have the following users:
    | name           |
    | Chandler Bing  |
    | Some Other Guy |
```

Then in your step definitions, you would do what the web steps were doing:

```
Given /^I create the following users:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |row|
    visit new_user_path
    fill_in 'Name', with: row['name']
    click_button 'Create User'
  end
end

Then /^I should have the following users:$/ do |table|
  # Ensure users with same name are taken into account
  table.hashes.size.should == User.count

  table.hashes.each do |row|
    user = User.find_by_name(row['name'])
    user.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

A few notes about this approach:

1. It allows your steps to be reusable. If you want to test the negative path and try adding an invalid user you wouldn't have to write a new step.
2. Less boilerplate code in the feature file. If you have a stakeholder, it should be easier for them to read the steps.
3. You will actually be learning capybara, which I know I personally took for granted with the web steps.
4. You can add a bunch of users with much less code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Beerlington. For some reason your suggestion seems unrelaible to me. What if I have several people with the same name? How can I know in this case that the user is the one that I created but not the one with the same name? Your solution is highly depends on uniqueness of a model attribute.

Comment: Great question! Good testing is about having confidence in your test scenarios. This was merely an example showing an alternate way of writing cucumber scenarios that gives you some additional flexibility. There's nothing stopping you from adding an additional assertion to the Then step which checks that the size of the table is equal to the number of records in the database. I'll update my answer to give an example of how this might work.